# How do you make a surface with no imperfections look good?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm trying to model/render this dalek is realistic is I can, but I can't really see any imperfections in the grey surface. Is there anything I can do to make it not look too flat? For context, the surface is moulded fibreglass painted grey.

I'm also using cycles.

[image]

Comment: imperfection and flat are not the same thing... to give it more volume you should create a new light

Comment: I meant the surface itself. Something I can do to still make it look like the reference, without looking like a default material coloured grey.

Comment: add a bit of texture, like dirt/rust?